# Enable deep linking for android for various structured urls

Tags: android, webview

I've already enabled deep linking & it opens app from url. However it opens only the main url i.e. `m.example.com` & not `m.example.com\products\iphone-5s\`.

I'm using `WebView` to load my mobile website into an Android app.

Here's a code of xml file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data
        android:host="m.example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filer>
```

Java file:

```
private String url='m.example.com';

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    mainWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Can anybody help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Get the URL link with this code, right after `Uri data = intent.getData();`

```
String link = intent.getDataString();
```

Then, set simple if/else

```
    if (link == null) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("yourMainURL");
    } else {
        mWebView.loadUrl(link);
    }
```

Comment: The problem here, anyway, is that this works when he user hasn't launched the app yet. If he has, then the main URL is still loading, not the link. None really has a better solution?

Comment: Ok, when the app has been already opened, it will always load the url it got from the first intent, or main url if there was no intent, so any further deep link will not work,